# kafka consumer cannot connect to server: {test-topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} when SSL ACL is configured

Tags: linux, ssl, apache-kafka, acl

I have a kafka clustor, it works fine when there is no SSL enabled, and it works fine also when SSL is enabled. But it does not work when ACL is configured.

The client consumer cannot connect to server, following failure is reported:

```
[2018-12-21 15:07:38,930] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-86611]
Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 :
{test-topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

From sarama log, it said:

```
[sarama] 2018/12/22 09:15:21 client/metadata fetching metadata for [test-topic] from broker kafka1.oneorg.example.com:9093
[sarama] 2018/12/22 09:15:21 client/metadata found some partitions to be leaderless
```

But this is not true, there do have a leader node if we use 'kafka-topics.sh --describe' command.

My kafka version is: kafka_2.11-1.0.0.jar

When we looked back to the kafka server, the topic test-topic is existed there:

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe \
--zookeeper zookeeper1.example.com:2181 \
--topic test-topic
Topic:test-topic    PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 0    Leader: 3   Replicas: 4,2,3 Isr: 3
```

And, it works fine when no ACL is configured. I took following actions for ACL:
1. enable ACL for server side

```
    - KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
    - KAFKA_SUPER_USERS=User:Bob;User:Alice
```

2. add ACL configure items

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-acls.sh \
--authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=zookeeper1.example.com:2181 \
--add \
--allow-principal User:"C=cn,O=mycomp,OU=myorg,CN=client" \
--operation All \
--topic "test-topic" \
--group "*" \
--cluster
```

The command is success

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-acls.sh \
--authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=zookeeper1.oneorg.example.com:2181 \
--list --topic test-topic
Current ACLs for resource `Topic:test-topic`: 
User:C=cn,O=mycomp,OU=myorg,CN=client has Allow permission for operations: All from hosts: *
```

3. start consumer client

```
/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh
--bootstrap-server kafka1.example.com:9093
--topic test-topic --partition 0
--consumer.config kafka-client-ssl.properties
```

The kafka-client-ssl.properties content:

```
ootstrap.servers=kafka1.example.com:9093
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/work/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
ssl.keystore.location=/work/client.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.key.password=test1234
```

I don't know whether something i missed, can any export help me? thanks.

> $ /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper zookeeper1.oneorg.example.com:2181 --topic test-topic
>
> Topic:test-topic    PartitionCount:1 ReplicationFactor:1    Configs: Topic: test-topic Partition: 0
>       Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1

Comment: I would like to point out you have 2 missing ISR on that topic. If you're getting that error and missing replicas, there's other issues with cluster than just consumers

Comment: That's not the cause; I created another instance with just on kafka, replication factor=1, but got same failure message.

Comment: /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper zookeeper1.oneorg.example.com:2181 --topic test-topic
Topic:test-topic PartitionCount:1 ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
 Topic: test-topic Partition: 0 Leader: 1 Replicas: 1 Isr: 1

Comment: Anyway, after I upgrade zookeeper to a new version, this issue disappeared. so i think it should be an un-match issue between kafka and zookeeper. Thanks.

Comment: You mean upgrade zookeeper outside of the version provided by Kafka download? What version were you using and what are you using now?

Comment: It's not about the zookeeper version issue; the root cause is the SUBJ in certificate could have only CN field, all others should be removed. take my above example, firstly, i use "C=cn,O=mycomp,OU=myorg,CN=client", this cause the problem, and when i changed to "CN=client", the problem disappeared; so i think this should be a kafak/zookeeper problem.

Comment: I don't think that's true. Certificates should have more than only a common name